# Cordova CanvasToImagePlugin throws NullPointerException error while saving the image

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using this plugin
https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin for Cordova Phonegap application,
canvas to image plugin for saving the image into some folder in sd card.

But it throws null pointer exception. I tried on phone after deploying. Here is the stacktrace for the same.[image]